# How can I load multiple saved value registers to argument registers to be used in a function?

Tags: parameter-passing, mips, qtspim

I am trying to take user input of three integers and pass them to a function, fme, which should return x^k mod n.  When attempting to load the input from save registers to argument registers in order to run the function I get the error:

> spim: (parser) syntax error on line 38 of file C:/Users/tamar/OneDrive/Documents/MIPS Projects/project2.s
>     lw $a0, $s0

Any suggestions for how I can execute this are appreciated.  Here is my main.

```
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, out_string_x
syscall #print string (X)

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s0, $v0 #take user input

li $v0, 4
la $a0, out_string_x
syscall #print string (K)

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s1, $v0 #take user input

li $v0, 4
la $a0, out_string_x
syscall #print string (N)

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s2, $v0 #take user input

#call fme function
lw $a0, $s0
lw $a1, $s1
lw $a2, $s2
jal fme
sw $v0, answer

#Display result
li $v0, 4
la $a0, result_message
syscall

li $v0, 1
lw $a0, answer
syscall

#end program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: `lw` instruction is used to load a word from memory. To copy the contents of a register onto another register use instruction `move` which you have already used elsewhere in your program.

Comment: that was the issue, thanks for the help